# anchor tag href is different than what is set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I have an anchor tag that looks like this:

```
<a href="/folder/folderid">name</a>
```

On click of this anchor tag I'm doing this

```
    handleAnchorClick: function(e) {
        console.log("target:",e.target);
        console.log("href:",e.target.href);
        event.preventDefault();

        // navigate to this folder using my app router
        backbonerouter.navigate(e.target.href,{trigger:true}); //does not work as the value is wrong
        // tries to navigate to this: mydomain.com/mydomain.com/folder/folderid
    }
```

the console log statement gives me this:

```
target: <a href="/folder/folderid">name</a>
href: "https://mydomain.com/folder/folderid"  //instead of just /folder/folderid
```

What the hell is going on, how do I navigate to this folder id using my router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The href property, as in `element.href`, always returns an absolute URL containing the hostname etc.

If you just want the attributes value and not the absolute URL, you can do

```
e.target.getAttribute('href');
```

or with jQuery

```
$(e.target).attr('href');
```

not that in jQuery prop() would return the property, i.e. the absolute URL

```
$(e.target).prop('href');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/z4a37/)